# How to make an image not stretch

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, image-resizing

On my front page I want the post thumbnail to be the full width of the page. But I only want it to be the full width of the page up until the image width it was uploaded at.  So when the page gets bigger and bigger I want the image to stop being 100% once it gets to its actual image size and then just stay that size.  Right now I have figured out how to make the post thumbnail full width, however as the page gets bigger the image just stretches to fit 100%. How could I fix this?

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?>
```

```
.large-front-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Add max-width with the image' width.

Comment: But what if each post thumbnail is uploaded at a different size.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make 2 changes.

Right now you're setting the image width to 100%. When you set width to 100%, no matter what size the image was uploaded at, it's going to stretch to the width of the container. You need to set width to auto.

You then want to set a max-width of 100%. Those 2 properties combined will mean your image will scale responsively yet never exceed the original upload size.

```
.large-front-thumbnail {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you haven't altered any of your WordPress defaults, the image size will always be 150px by 150px.  How do you know?  Because you are passing the 'thumbnail' argument into `the_post_thumbnail`.

Therefore, as @pol said, setting a `max-width` rule of 150px will work.

[See more here about the behavior of `the_post_thumbnail`.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

Comment: but what if the photo I uploaded into the featured image spot is say 1700 × 1139? Then I would want the picture to be a max of 1700. If the photo was say 1000 x 500 I would want max-width to be 1000

Comment: @user6738171 Then be careful about using `the_post_thumbnail`, because as the documentation suggests, it will create a copy of your picture on upload that is cropped down to 150px by 150px automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need use "max-height" & "max-width", preferable add div container outside constraint outer image size.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <img src="https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx" alt="anything" style="position: absolute; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should be what you require:

```
.large-front-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```